# Как объединить несколько проектов в один?

Tags: c#

Предположим, есть несколько проектов винформ. Если сделать несколько проектов, то как объединить их в один, чтобы можно было переключаться между ними в программе?

Comment: «Переключаться между проектами» во время компиляции или во время выполнения?

Answer (score 1):

поместите их в один солюшн

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, вот так: [IL Merge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx). Эта утилита позволяет слить несколько сборок в одну.

Comment: @Modus, эта утилита предназначена для сшивания компонентов приложения в один исполняемый файл.

Comment: Да. Насколько конкретно сформулирован вопрос, настолько точен ответ.